# How to hide AC lines up against brick siding

Tags: hvac, brick, siding

I had this AC system installed, and didn't realize when asked about what location i'd prefer the compressor that it would look so ugly having it off the corner of the building instead of in the middle (due to the AC lines). The return line and electrical conduit are rather large and look rather unsightly as you can see. There was no option of making the lines exit the building right behind the unit without doing A LOT of drywall and interior reconstruction. My front steps are about 5ft to the right of the picture. So this ended up being an eyesore. [image]

Suggestions as to how I make this not look so hideous? The AC installer suggested I get some tin roof gutter and afix it sideways so to cover this. Seems like that would be just as ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options.

You can get some brown gutter downspouts, cut out the back end and mount it over the pipes. I think the downspout will look better versus the gutter because of it's uniform shape. This is commonly done in my area but it is installed at the same time as the pipes so that the pipes can run through it without having to cut the downspout to mount over the pipes.

The brown downspout will be less noticeable but if you want you can try to paint it to match the brickwork.

You can plant some shrubs in front of them.

Or you can do both.

Comment: Most complete answer with multiple options. Appreciate it.

I think i'm going to do both only with Sheldon's answer as well and have it be a brick planter box. This way, it's 100% hidden even if shrubs die off or don't totally cover it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Give the ivy a few more weeks, and some compost to help it along.

Wrap the bundle in a mesh to give the ivy more purchase. or put a short section of trellis in front of the bundle/wall for it to grab onto. Disappearing bundle, like magic.

Shrubs if you feel you must, but given the ivy is already working the area, let it work.

Comment: I like the idea of the trellis, but every winter you can see it again when the ivy goes dormant. Also, was told I should start keeping the ivy away from the bricks and consider planting something else. If you let Ivy get really crazy, it will destroy your brick.

Answer (score 1):

You could always put some sort of planter box in front/over it, like an upside down window valance.

Something like a [brick planter box](http://teardropsonroses.blogspot.com/2014/06/garden-brick-planter-designs.html)

Comment: I like this answer, and +1 for providing the link.